# npm build to generate two targets

Tags: npm, npm-scripts, npm-build

Let's say I have core1.js, core2.js and wrapper.js.
How do I config NPM to generate two targets:

- core.js which includes core1 and core2
- all.js which includes everything

The scenario is that I need publish all.js for the public; and core.js internally for another team and another project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this one --- if it is TS, let npm to run TSC based on two different tsconfig.
If it is JS, can just concatenate with two different bat files.